# What was the Soviet reaction to the revelations about secret US programs like Projects ARTICHOKE, MKULTRA, MOCKINGBIRD, etc., revealed in the 1970s?

Tags: soviet-union, espionage, us-congress, 1970s, cia

I imagine the perception among the party elites in Moscow would have been that all these programs, projects, experiments and so on were initiated with them in mind, and would have inevitably been directed against them.

The most dramatic moments of the Church and Pike committee hearings such as the Heart attack gun, mind control drugs, domestic wire tapping, domestic bioweapon testing, etc., being on the public record would surely have been difficult to fully hide among the segment of the Soviet population with foreign contacts. Not to mention highly tempting propaganda targets.

But was it ever officially revealed to the public, ideologically denounced, or kept secret?
And were any counter projects, retaliatory measures, ideological shifts, etc., ever carried out, that we know of?

The only significant and clearly retaliatory response that I could find credible evidence for was the establishment of a ‘military unit 10003’ in the late 1980s that was apparently focused on ‘parapsychology’ i.e. ESP, telepathy, clairvoyance, etc., presumably to counter the likewise US efforts. see: rbth.com/lifestyle/330258-russia-psychic-soldiers-majic The soviet bioweapons, special forces, PSYOPS, etc., programs seemed to have existed prior to the mid 1970s so it’s not clear whether any later expansion could be considered retaliatory or because of organizational dynamics.

Comment: I am certainly not expert on such things, but I'd wager that the Soviets knew of the _existence_ of these programs, if not all the details. Maybe quite a few of the details... But I have no sources, only extrapolations from reading accounts of cold war spying, cryptography stuff from the last 80+ years, computer security stuff from the last 30+. I have no access to classified info. :)  (So, to be clear, they were not surprised at all, regardless of their official statements for political purposes...)

Comment: I very much doubt that average Moscovites (BTW, why restrict only to Moscow in all of the USSR?) knew much about any these or had particularly strong opinion on them. My guess is that this information was drowned in other anti-imperialist propaganda (think Watergate, coup in Chile, Yom Kippur war, oil crisis, war in Angola, stagflation, just to name a few items). Top it up with instability in PRC, revolution in Iran and war in Afghanistan. By comparison, what you are listing are just peanuts.

Comment: [What has your preliminary research shown](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the input, I meant ‘Moscow’ as a metaphor for the party elites in Moscow, so I clarified my wording in the original.

Comment: Huh, they’re doing it also…

Comment: @MCW The only significant and clearly retaliatory response that I could find credible evidence for was the establishment of a ‘military unit 10003’ in the late 1980s that was apparently focused on ‘parapsychology’ i.e. ESP, telepathy, clairvoyance, etc., presumably to counter the likewise US efforts. see: https://www.rbth.com/lifestyle/330258-russia-psychic-soldiers-majic  The soviet bioweapons, special forces, PSYOPS, etc., programs seemed to have existed prior to the mid 1970s so it’s not clear whether any later expansion could be considered retaliatory or because of organizational dynamics.

Comment: That should be in the question

Comment: The question is still muddled: On one hand, your edit indicates that you are asking about CPSU elites. On the other hand, you are writing "being on the public record would surely have been difficult to fully hide among the segment of the Soviet population with foreign contacts. Not to mention highly tempting propaganda targets," which is indicative of a different segment of population (not sure which one, you have in mind). Communist Party elites got their information through other channels, not "contains with foreigners."

Comment: Plus: The opening sentence ("I imagine...") does not seem to be rooted in facts. A typical communist party boss would worried about his subordinates trying to unseat him (rarely, her) or trying to unseat his superior to move up in the Party hierarchy, not about CIA agents walking through the streets of Moscow attempting a PSYOP against him. For instance, Brezhnev would be worried about Andropov's (the head of KGB through 1970s) loyalty to him (Tsvigun's role as Andropov's first deputy was to watch Andropov).

Comment: @MoisheKohan What makes you believe I was trying to refer to the same group of people in both paragraphs?

Answer (score 9):

I think such news would find a place in short column articles in newspapers and in cartoons on international topics along with themes of racism, war crimes and religious backwardness and in political monographs but otherwise were little discussed in depth.

On the other hand, in Soviet sci-fi a topic where the capitalist or fascist governments or companies covertly add various bio-active substances to the food of the subjects or personnel or prisoners for experiments was quite prominent. For instance, the "Clay God" novel by Anatoly Dneprov employs the topic.

So, I would say it was mostly perceived as "capitalist business as usual".

[Here is a Soviet book](https://books.google.com/books?id=swX7AgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA166&ots=lTqM-5LOTE&dq=%D0%BC%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%81%D1%80&hl=ru&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%81%D1%80&f=false) from 1986 by N.N. Yakovlev "CIA against the USSR" that discusses the topic.

P.S. @rs.29 in his answer pointed out an important factor: the Soviet reaction would depend on whether the USSR was engaged in similar activity.

Regarding the topic at hand, the USSR was engaged in similar (but not exactly the same) actions.

First, as @rs.29 correctly pointed out, the USSR widely practiced putting the dissidents in mental institutions.
In those institutions the medics could and did use various kinds of highly-active substances on the inmates.

Could they use something entirely new to test? Well, I think to test something entirely new they would rather choose usual psychos first, not the politicals, and even for that possibly there were legal regulations, that is the medicines should be tested on volunteers first, but you know, it is easy to get consent from an unfree inmate or their custodians.

The second thing is that the USSR widely practiced testing various damaging factors (such as radiation) on unfree military personnel.

Whether such tests would require consent probably would depend on whether the damage inflicted on health exceeded some permitted limits. The limits for exposure of military personnel were very generous, basically assuming a nuclear war circumstances.

The personnel would be informed that they were participating in the test, and the measures to limit the exposure to some max permitted dosage would be taken but otherwise the soldiers would be simply ordered to go into radioactive area (with intended protection equipment).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the book. It is quite curious if the popular perception was that the West, or at least America, was presumed to be so degenerate that all these secrets would be considered business as usual. How could the Soviet Union have ever collapsed if folks genuinely believed that their system would protect them the presumably limitless deprivations of capitalism, etc.?

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo Russians are very cynical, so they could at the same time believe in dirty things done by Capitalist governments and in higher standard of living for at least portion of the population in the West for those who are lucky. People who wanted to live under capitalism did so because of many kind of sausage in the stores, even if there would be some fascist-style violations. Also, nobody publicly advocated for "capitalism" during the Perestroika, the people were told the transition was to "true Leninism", "market economy" and "democracy".

Answer (score 6):

### Soviet modus operandi

First thing to consider is **did the Soviets know about these experiments before things went public**. Soviet intelligence agencies like [KGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB) or [GRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRU) could have known something due to their wide agent network. But if they did, they may not have gone public with that knowledge, most likely to protect their agents who may have been still alive and living in the US, or have close relatives there.

Second thing to consider is **what would they have done with such knowledge**? The Soviets could have been interested in the results of these experiments in order to know how to counter possible effects or even employ them themselves. Of course, there was always the possibility to embarrass opponents and show to the world how evil the US and its allies truly were. In that case, the Soviets would not directly present evidence (let's say by spokesman of Foreign Ministry). Instead, again to protect their agents and to appear shocked as everyone else, **they would leak incriminating data to the Western press**. The Soviets did have informal contacts with several journalists ready to use anonymous sources, for example it was long suspected that [Seymour Hersh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seymour_Hersh) actually got in contact with Soviet informants when he blew a lid on [CIA Family Jewels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Jewels_(Central_Intelligence_Agency)).

The third thing to consider is **what would the Soviets have done when the information became public**. The Soviet government wanted to preserve an aura of reliability, especially when addressing a foreign audience. When addressing the Western public, they especially would use something already known to them or easily verifiable.  But even in this case they would have a two-pronged propaganda strategy. If they wanted to point out something that **the USSR was not doing**, they would simply go ahead and tell that straight away. For example, they accused US many times of bombing civilians in Vietnam, including using inhumane ammunition like napalm against children. At that point of time the USSR was not engaged in open wars, so they used opportunities to portray Americans as murderous barbarians - and it was pretty successful.

However, if they had information about some nefarious acts that **the USSR was also doing**, they would refrain for commenting right away. Instead, they would use them **to portray Western hypocrisy**. For example, if the US attacked the USSR for [putting dissidents in psychiatric institutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_abuse_of_psychiatry_in_the_Soviet_Union), they would respond that those attacks were coming from a country doing psychiatric experiments on their own population. Without such provocation, the Soviets would refrain from using "the dirt" directly, as seems to be the case in this situation. Barring a few publications for domestic consumption that can be still found on [the Russian internet](https://psychosearch.ru/napravleniya/social/651-mind-control-bluebird-and-mk-ultra), the Soviets were content to let the Western press smear their own governments. They had their [own secrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_laboratory_of_the_Soviet_secret_services) to keep, and did not want to be a proverbial black pot.